# 3D indices access in CUDA for nonlinear diffusion

Tags: 3d, cuda

I'm writing my first CUDA code for 2D/3D nonlinear diffusion. The 2D case is working fine, however I'm struggling with the 3D one. Basically I'm getting zeros on the stage of finite differences calculation and surprisingly the 'deltaN' (pls see code below) is giving the right answer but the other ones are not working (zeros in answer). I'm trying to process 256x256x256 volume. Any suggestions please? Thanks!

```
 #define BLKXSIZE 8
 #define BLKYSIZE 8
 #define BLKZSIZE 8
 #define idivup(a, b) ( ((a)%(b) != 0) ? (a)/(b)+1 : (a)/(b) )

void AnisotropDiff_GPU(double* A, double* B, int N, int M, int Z, double sigma, int iter, double tau, int type)
{ 
// Nonlinear Diffusion in 3D 
double *Ad;     

dim3 dimBlock(BLKXSIZE, BLKYSIZE, BLKZSIZE);           
dim3 dimGrid(idivup(N,BLKXSIZE), idivup(M,BLKYSIZE), idivup(Z,BLKYSIZE));    

cudaMalloc((void**)&Ad,N*M*Z*sizeof(double));  
cudaMemcpy(Ad,A,N*M*Z*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);  

int n = 1;
while (n <= iter) {    
anis_diff3D<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(Ad, N, M, Z, sigma, iter, tau, type);  
n++;}
cudaMemcpy(B,Ad,N*M*Z*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaFree(Ad);
}
```

and here is a part for calculating finite differences

```
 __global__ void anis_diff3D(double* A, int N, int M, int Z, double sigma, int iter, double tau, int type)
{

 int xIndex = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
 int yIndex = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
 int zIndex = blockDim.z * blockIdx.z + threadIdx.z;

 if ( (xIndex < N) && (yIndex < M) && (zIndex < Z) )
 {
    int index_out = xIndex + M*yIndex + N*M*zIndex;

    double deltaN=0, deltaS=0, deltaW=0, deltaE=0, deltaU=0, deltaD=0;
    double cN, cS, cW, cE, cU, cD;

    int indexN = (xIndex-1) + M*yIndex + N*M*zIndex;
    int indexS = (xIndex+1) + M*yIndex + N*M*zIndex;
    int indexW = xIndex + M*(yIndex-1) + N*M*zIndex;
    int indexE = xIndex + M*(yIndex+1) + N*M*zIndex;
    int indexU = xIndex + M*yIndex + N*M*(zIndex-1);
    int indexD = xIndex + M*yIndex + N*M*(zIndex+1);


    if (xIndex>1)
        deltaN = A[indexN]-A[index_out];
    if (xIndex<N)
        deltaS = A[indexS]-A[index_out];    
    if (yIndex>1)
        deltaW = A[indexW]-A[index_out];    
    if (yIndex<M)
        deltaE = A[indexE]-A[index_out];
    if (zIndex>1)
        deltaU = A[indexU]-A[index_out];    
    if (zIndex<Z)
        deltaD = A[indexD]-A[index_out];

   A[index_out] = deltaN ; // works for deltaN but not for deltaS, deltaW... . 

 }
```

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Since you haven't indicated any of the dimensions you are passing to the code, there may be an issue there.  I have 2 suggestions: 1.) do cuda [error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) on all cuda calls.  2.) Run your code through `cuda-memcheck`

Comment: What is the value of BLKZSIZE?

Comment: thanks Robert. I'm using
#define BLKXSIZE 8
#define BLKYSIZE 8
#define BLKZSIZE 8
#define idivup(a, b) ( ((a)%(b) != 0) ? (a)/(b)+1 : (a)/(b) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have out-of-bounds indexing for some of the values you are trying to compute in the kernel.

If you compile your code with the last kernel line like this:

```
A[index_out] = deltaS ;
```

and then run it with `cuda-memcheck`, cuda-memcheck will report out of bounds accesses:

```
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 8
=========     at 0x000000b0 in anis_diff3D(double*, int, int, int, double, int, double, int)
=========     by thread (7,7,7) in block (31,31,31)
=========     Address 0x408100000 is out of bounds
```

So what is going on?  Let's take a look at your index calculation:

```
int indexS = (xIndex+1) + M*yIndex + N*M*zIndex;
```

For the very last thread in the grid (thread (7,7,7) in block (31, 31, 31)), this index calculation indexes *beyond* the end of your memory array `A` in this line:

```
    deltaS = A[indexS]-A[index_out];
```

You'll have to handle these boundary conditions in order to make things run properly.

While we are at it, if you had done [error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api), your kernel would have thrown an error.  Note that depending on which value you select to store at the end of the kernel, the compiler may optimize out the other calculations, leading to a kernel which appears to run correctly, (for example if you store deltaN instead of deltaS).   Here's an example of code with error checking in it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

 #define BLKXSIZE 8
 #define BLKYSIZE 8
 #define BLKZSIZE 8
 #define idivup(a, b) ( ((a)%(b) != 0) ? (a)/(b)+1 : (a)/(b) )
 #define sizeX 256
 #define sizeY 256
 #define sizeZ 256
 #define sizeT (sizeX*sizeY*sizeZ)


 __global__ void anis_diff3D(double* A, int N, int M, int Z, double sigma, int iter, double tau, int type)
{

 int xIndex = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
 int yIndex = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
 int zIndex = blockDim.z * blockIdx.z + threadIdx.z;

 if ( (xIndex < N) && (yIndex < M) && (zIndex < Z) )
 {
    int index_out = xIndex + M*yIndex + N*M*zIndex;

    double deltaN=0, deltaS=0, deltaW=0, deltaE=0, deltaU=0, deltaD=0;
    double cN, cS, cW, cE, cU, cD;

    int indexN = (xIndex-1) + M*yIndex + N*M*zIndex;
    if (indexN > ((N*M*Z)-1)) indexN = (N*M*Z) -1;
    if (indexN < 0) indexN = 0;
    int indexS = (xIndex+1) + M*yIndex + N*M*zIndex;
    if (indexS > ((N*M*Z)-1)) indexS = (N*M*Z) -1;
    if (indexS < 0) indexS = 0;
    int indexW = xIndex + M*(yIndex-1) + N*M*zIndex;
    if (indexW > ((N*M*Z)-1)) indexW = (N*M*Z) -1;
    if (indexW < 0) indexW = 0;
    int indexE = xIndex + M*(yIndex+1) + N*M*zIndex;
    if (indexE > ((N*M*Z)-1)) indexE = (N*M*Z) -1;
    if (indexE < 0) indexE = 0;
    int indexU = xIndex + M*yIndex + N*M*(zIndex-1);
    if (indexU > ((N*M*Z)-1)) indexU = (N*M*Z) -1;
    if (indexU < 0) indexU = 0;
    int indexD = xIndex + M*yIndex + N*M*(zIndex+1);
    if (indexD > ((N*M*Z)-1)) indexD = (N*M*Z) -1;
    if (indexD < 0) indexD = 0;    

    if (xIndex>1)
        deltaN = A[indexN]-A[index_out];
    if (xIndex<N)
        deltaS = A[indexS]-A[index_out];
    if (yIndex>1)
        deltaW = A[indexW]-A[index_out];
    if (yIndex<M)
        deltaE = A[indexE]-A[index_out];
    if (zIndex>1)
        deltaU = A[indexU]-A[index_out];
    if (zIndex<Z)
        deltaD = A[indexD]-A[index_out];

   A[index_out] = deltaS; // works for deltaN but not for deltaS, deltaW... .

 }
}
void AnisotropDiff_GPU(double* A, double* B, int N, int M, int Z, double sigma, int iter, double tau, int type)
{
  // Nonlinear Diffusion in 3D
  double *Ad;

  dim3 dimBlock(BLKXSIZE, BLKYSIZE, BLKZSIZE);
  dim3 dimGrid(idivup(N,BLKXSIZE), idivup(M,BLKYSIZE), idivup(Z,BLKYSIZE));

  cudaMalloc((void**)&Ad,N*M*Z*sizeof(double));
  cudaCheckErrors("cm1");
  cudaMemcpy(Ad,A,N*M*Z*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("cc1");
  int n = 1;
  while (n <= iter) {
    anis_diff3D<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(Ad, N, M, Z, sigma, iter, tau, type);
    n++;
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaCheckErrors("kernel");
  }
  cudaMemcpy(B,Ad,N*M*Z*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cc2");
  cudaFree(Ad);
}

int main(){

  double *A;
  A = (double *)malloc(sizeT * sizeof(double));
  if (A == 0) {printf("malloc fail\n"); return 1;}

  for (int i=0; i< sizeT; i++)
    A[i] = (double)(rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);

  printf("data:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    printf("A[%d] = %f\n", i, A[i]);

  AnisotropDiff_GPU(A, A, sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ, 0.5f, 3, 0.5, 3);
  printf("results:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    printf("A[%d] = %f\n", i, A[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**  I've edited the above code to clamp the index calculations to the boundaries of the defined array.  This should prevent out-of-bounds access.  Whether it is sensible from an algorithm standpoint I don't know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Robert! However with error checking Matlab crashes now without any messages. I'm calling for cuda kernal from the Matlab mex function. Any ideas how I should handle boundary conditions for blocks?

Comment: If you use my code directly in matlab, it will crash.  That is expected.  You have to *fix the problems first*.  The problem is not that you didn't have error checking.  The problem is that you have written an algorithm that accesses out of bounds of your defined array.  You need to fix that.  I don't know how your algorithm should behave at the boundaries.  I'll edit my code to just clamp to the boundaries.

Comment: Thanks Robert. This solved my problem, miraculously 12 times faster than the Matlab implementation. I just thought that error checking can stop/exit the kernel but not whole Matlab ) Anyway I have to work more on understanding what going on on thread/block level to avoid similar problems. Sorry I cannot vote up because of my low rating, but thanks a lot for help!